# Most efficient way to merge timestamp column in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

What is the most efficient way to merge two columns in a spark dataframe?

I have two columns that mean the same. The null values from `timestamp` should be filled with the values from `toAppendData_timestamp`

When both columns have values, that means the values are equal...

I have this:

```
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
|           timestamp|toAppendData_timestamp|   value|
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
|2016-03-24 22:11:...|                  null|    null|
|                null|  2016-03-24 22:12:...|0.015625|
|                null|  2016-03-19 15:54:...|   5.375|
|2016-03-19 15:55:...|  2016-03-19 15:55:...| 5.78125|
|2016-03-19 15:56:...|                  null|    null|
|2016-03-24 22:11:...|  2016-03-24 22:11:...| 0.15625|
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
```

And I need this:

```
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
|    timestamp_merged|toAppendData_timestamp|   value|
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
|2016-03-24 22:11:...|                  null|    null|
|2016-03-24 22:12:...|  2016-03-24 22:12:...|0.015625|
|2016-03-19 15:54:...|  2016-03-19 15:54:...|   5.375|
|2016-03-19 15:55:...|  2016-03-19 15:55:...| 5.78125|
|2016-03-19 15:56:...|                  null|    null|
|2016-03-24 22:11:...|  2016-03-24 22:11:...| 0.15625|
+--------------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I have tried this, but with no success:

```
appendedData = appendedData['timestamp'].fillna(appendedData['toAppendData_timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're looking for is `coalesce`. You can import it from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col
```

and use:

```
appendedData.withColumn(
    'timestamp_merged', 
    coalesce(col('timestamp'), col('toAppendData_timestamp'))
)
```